# Python - Convert each integer to string in list and add a comma

Tags: python, string, list

I am new to python. I need to create a list of integers from 1 to 70, but for each integer I want to make it a string and a comma after it and store it in another list.

Ex:

```
for i in range (1,71):

    list_of_ints.append(i)

{ Some code 

}
```

it should then be something like this

```
columns = ['1','2','3','4'.......'70']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[str(i) for i in range(1, 71)]`. This gives you the list of `str(i)` for all `i` in `range(1, 71)`. The function `str(i)` returns `i` as a `str` value instead of as an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(1,71):
    l.append(str(i))
>>> l
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [str(x) for x in range(1, 71)]
```

Using a list comprehension to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to help you here:

```
>>> list_of_ints = range(1, 71)
>>> list_of_ints = map(str, list_of_ints)
>>> print list_of_ints
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70']
>>>
```